# Add an image at the top of the pdf with 0 margin, however the rest of the body has left and right margin/padding (Itext7, C#)

Tags: c#, itext7, html-to-pdf, .net-4.6.1

I want to to create a pdf that contains a Bulletin logo/image with 0 margin at the top of the 1st page. However I want whitespace/margin for the content in the body, that looks like this:

[image]

I am using IText7 with C# (.net 4.6.1) to try and achieve this. I set the document margins to 0, then add the image and iterate through html (which comes from my WYSIWYG editor) break it down into elements and add each element to the document. However when I do this, it sets the margin of the content in the body as 0 as well.

[image]

Is there was a way to do this, where I can add a margin to each element that I add in the body? Or any other method? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
                string bulletinpdf = Server.MapPath("~/generatedfiles/pdf/text.pdf");
                PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(bulletinpdf);
                PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
                pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
                Document document2 = new Document(pdfDoc);
                document2.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);        //set document margins to 0 here

                string outputpdf = Server.MapPath("~/Components/Images/bulletinheader.jpg");
                ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(outputpdf);
                Image image2 = new Image(imageData);
                //image2.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);      //i've tried commenting out the above and trying this. to no avail.
                document2.Add(image2);

                ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
                IList elements = (IList)HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(createForm.BulletinText, properties);
                foreach (IElement element in elements)
                { 
                    document2.Add((IBlockElement) element);
                }

                document2.Close();
```

Here is the header image:
[image]

Here is the html for creatForm.BulletinText (html that gets extracted from the CK content editor) I've emptied the image element, but have attached the image below for replication purposes:

```
<p><img alt="" src="" style="float:left; height:400px; width:400px">Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a test</td>
            <td>This is a test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a test</td>
            <td>This is a test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a test</td>
            <td>This is a test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the image to place in html img element and modify src to include path to this picture:
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you add the sample of your HTML so that your code is reproducible?

Comment: I am not able to add the html, as it extends the allowable characters in my question past the max allowed. I have base64 images which extend the html out greatly. However it is just a header image (Bulletin logo in blue) with content beneath it, which can be any text for all I care. If you can share your email, I can send the html over to you. Or if you have any other options of getting the html to you, I'm open to it.

Comment: You can always minimize your HTML file and your image files. You can use element placeholders instead of images or use a PNG image with plan filling which should not occupy much space

Comment: Alright sir, I added the header image so it can be downloaded. And also the html with the image attached. Please let me know if anything needs to be added/changed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired goal by adapting the HTML slightly, and all the code you have to write is a couple of lines:

```
FileInfo htmlPath = new FileInfo("C:/Users/x/Desktop/html.html");

HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileStream(htmlPath.FullName, FileMode.Open), 
new FileStream("C:/Users/x/Desktop/out.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate),
new ConverterProperties().SetBaseUri(htmlPath.Directory.FullName));
```

Now in your HTML you need to add the `<img>` which will contain the header, set an ID to it and set its with (matching the width of your PDF):

```
<img id="header" style="width: 210mm" src="header.jpg"/>
```

Then we set all the right and left margins on the document to 0 (we will compensate it by setting margins to `<body>` element), and the top margin for the first page to 0. We mark the logo image as a running element and include it to the margin box area of the first page. All with the CSS declarative means!

```
<style>

@page {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

@page:first {
    margin-top: 138pt;
    
    @top-left {
        content: element(header);
    }
}

#header {
    position: running(header);
}
</style>
```

Full HTML (I've placed the table on the next page just to verify the second page looks as expected as well):

```
<head>
<style>

@page {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

@page:first {
    margin-top: 138pt;
    
    @top-left {
        content: element(header);
    }
}

#header {
    position: running(header);
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="margin-left: 36pt; margin-right: 36pt;">

<img id="header" style="width: 210mm" src="header.jpg"/>

<p>Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123Testing 123&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>


<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px; page-break-before: always;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a test</td>
            <td>This is a test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a test</td>
            <td>This is a test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a test</td>
            <td>This is a test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

Visual result:

[image: result]

Comment: thank you sir. Give me a couple week's to try this out. And i'll accept as answer once I am able to verify. Again, thank you!